# How this visualisation was made?

Tags: visualization, distribution, infographics

I really like how this visualization represents the survey participants.

Is any tool for that?  (Or R/python library?)

[image]

Answer (score 4):

My go to library would be matplotlib, with which it is relatively easy to generate something similar.

I don't have the correct font family to render the exact output as above, but this hopefully illustrates the point
[image]

**Source Code**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# Create the data to plot on
# create a 2d array of evenly-spaced points on a grid
xy_range = np.arange(10.)
data = pd.DataFrame([[x, y] for x in xy_range for y in xy_range], columns=['X', 'Y'])

# color the points
# all green first and then with exceptions
data['color'] = 'green'
data.loc[(data['X']>=0)&(data['Y']==1), 'color'] = 'yellow'
data.loc[(data['X']>=8)&(data['Y']==2), 'color'] = 'yellow'
data.loc[(data['X']>=6)&(data['Y']==0), 'color'] = 'blue'

# We'll use this to calculate axis fractions
max_x = data['X'].max()
max_y = data['Y'].max()

fig, currAX = plt.subplots(figsize=(5,5), facecolor='lightgray')

# plot/mark each point as an annotation
# we do this so we can get a custom emoji instead a marker
for x0, y0, color in zip(data['X'], data['Y'], data['color']):    
    plt.annotate(s=u'\u263B', xy=(x0/max_x, y0/max_y), fontname='STIXGeneral', color=color, size=15, ha='center', va='center')

# clear the axis lables, ticks, and lines        
currAX.get_xaxis().set_visible(False) 
currAX.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)       
plt.axis('off')

plt.show();
```

Answer (score 3):

With [Wolfram Language](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/) you may use [`"Icon"`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/entity/Icon.html) [`Entity`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Entity.html) and [`ConstantArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConstantArray.html) to create lists of `"Crayola"` [`ColorData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorData.html) colored icons and display with [`Multicolumn`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Multicolumn.html) 24 columns wide.

```
palette = <|"SeaGreen" -> 135, "Razzmatazz" -> 146, "Yellow" -> 18, "TurquoiseBlue" -> 13|>;
Multicolumn[
 Flatten@
  KeyValueMap[
    With[{i =
        Graphics[{ColorData["Crayola", #1], List @@ Entity["Icon", "MensRoom"]["Image"]},
         Background -> Black,
         ImageSize -> 12]
       },
      ConstantArray[i, #2]
      ] &
    ]@palette,
 24,
 Spacings -> .2,
 Frame -> True,
 FrameStyle -> Directive[Thickness[3], Black],
 Background -> Black,
 Appearance -> "Horizontal"
 ]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

#### Update

The above can be generalised into a function that takes an [`Association`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html) of colours to number of icons, a set of graphics primitives for the icon (icons are [`FilledCurve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FilledCurve.html)s), and some additional display parameters.

```
ClearAll[iconChart]
Options[iconChart] = {Options[Multicolumn], Options[Graphics]};
SetOptions[iconChart,
  {
   Background -> Black,
   ImageSize -> 12,
   Spacings -> .2,
   Frame -> True,
   FrameStyle -> Directive[Thickness[3], Black],
   Appearance -> "Horizontal"
   }];
iconChart[pallet_, icon_, columns_, opts : OptionsPattern[iconChart]] :=
 Multicolumn[
  Flatten@
   KeyValueMap[
     With[{i =
         Graphics[{#1, icon}, 
          Frame -> None, 
          FilterRules[{opts, Options[iconChart]}, Options[Graphics]]]
        },
       ConstantArray[i, #2]
       ] &
     ]@pallet,
  columns,
  FilterRules[{opts, Options[iconChart]}, {Options[Multicolumn]}]
  ]
```

Then the above can be charted with

```
iconChart[
 <|
  ColorData["Crayola", "SeaGreen"] -> 135,
  ColorData["Crayola", "Razzmatazz"] -> 146,
  ColorData["Crayola", "Yellow"] -> 18,
  ColorData["Crayola", "TurquoiseBlue"] -> 13
  |> ,
 List @@ Entity["Icon", "MensRoom"]["Image"], 
 24
]
```

Adding random colour and icon selection generates a different chart on each evaluation.

```
iconChart[
 AssociationThread[
  RandomSample[
   Values@KeyDrop["Black"]@ColorData["Crayola", "ColorRules"], 5],
  RandomInteger[{3, 15}, 5]
  ],
 List @@ RandomEntity["Icon"]["Image"],
 10,
 ImageSize -> 30]
```

For example,

> [image: Mathematica graphics]
>
> [image: Mathematica graphics]
>
> [image: Mathematica graphics]

and so on.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

#### Waffle Chart

---

These are called Waffle Chart. A Waffle Chart is a gripping visualization technique that is normally created to display progress towards goals. A waffle chart shows progress towards a target or a completion percentage. There is a grid of small cells, of which coloured cells represent the data. A chart can consist of one category or several categories. Multiple waffle charts can be put together to show a comparison between different charts.

**[PyWaffle](https://github.com/gyli/PyWaffle)** is an open source, MIT-licensed Python package for plotting waffle charts.

It provides a Figure constructor class Waffle, which could be passed to matplotlib.pyplot.figure and generates a matplotlib Figure object.

- [PyPI Page](https://pypi.org/project/pywaffle/)
- [Documentation](http://pywaffle.readthedocs.io/)

Some examples:

**Plot with Icons - Pictogram Chart**

```
data = {'Democratic': 48, 'Republican': 46, 'Libertarian': 3}
fig = plt.figure(
    FigureClass=Waffle, 
    rows=5, 
    values=data, 
    colors=["#232066", "#983D3D", "#DCB732"],
    legend={'loc': 'upper left', 'bbox_to_anchor': (1, 1)},
    icons='child', 
    font_size=12, 
    icon_legend=True
)
plt.show()
```

[image]

**Multiple Plots in One Chart**

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'labels': ['Hillary Clinton', 'Donald Trump', 'Others'],
        'Virginia': [1981473, 1769443, 233715],
        'Maryland': [1677928, 943169, 160349],
        'West Virginia': [188794, 489371, 36258],
    },
).set_index('labels')

# A glance of the data:
#                  Maryland  Virginia  West Virginia
# labels                                            
# Hillary Clinton   1677928   1981473         188794
# Donald Trump       943169   1769443         489371
# Others             160349    233715          36258


fig = plt.figure(
    FigureClass=Waffle,
    plots={
        '311': {
            'values': data['Virginia'] / 30000,
            'labels': [f"{k} ({v})" for k, v in data['Virginia'].items()],
            'legend': {'loc': 'upper left', 'bbox_to_anchor': (1.05, 1), 'fontsize': 8},
            'title': {'label': '2016 Virginia Presidential Election Results', 'loc': 'left'}
        },
        '312': {
            'values': data['Maryland'] / 30000,
            'labels': [f"{k} ({v})" for k, v in data['Maryland'].items()],
            'legend': {'loc': 'upper left', 'bbox_to_anchor': (1.2, 1), 'fontsize': 8},
            'title': {'label': '2016 Maryland Presidential Election Results', 'loc': 'left'}
        },
        '313': {
            'values': data['West Virginia'] / 30000,
            'labels': [f"{k} ({v})" for k, v in data['West Virginia'].items()],
            'legend': {'loc': 'upper left', 'bbox_to_anchor': (1.3, 1), 'fontsize': 8},
            'title': {'label': '2016 West Virginia Presidential Election Results', 'loc': 'left'}
        },
    },
    rows=5,  # outside parameter applied to all subplots
    colors=["#2196f3", "#ff5252", "#999999"],  # outside parameter applied to all subplots
    figsize=(9, 5)
)
plt.show()
```

[image]

For more,

- plotting [Waffle charts in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41400136/14045537)
- plotting [Waffle charts in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27401806/14045537)